# Arrays aren't behaving as I'm expecting

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

Pointers are still a little confusing to me. I want the split function to copy negative elements of an array into a new array, and positive elements to be copied into another new array. A different function prints the variables. I've included that function but I don't think it is the problem. When the arrays are printed, all elements are 0:

```
Enter number of elements: 5   
Enter list:1 -1 2 -2 3
Negative elements:
0 0 
Non-Negative elements:
0 0 0
```

I assume that the problem is that in the split function below i need to pass the parameters differently. I've tried using '*' and '**' (no quotes) for passing the parameters but I get error messages, I may have done so incorrectly.

```
void split(int alpha[], int bravo[], int charlie[], int aSize, int bSize, int cSize) {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < aSize; ++i) {
  if (alpha[i] < 0) {
    alpha[i] = bravo[a];
    ++a;
  }
  else {
    alpha[i] = charlie[b];
    ++b;
  }   
}
 if (a + b != aSize) {
   cout << "SOMETHING HAS GONE HORRIBLY WRONG!";
   exit(0);
 }
}
```

my main function (all arrays are required to be pointers):

```
int num_elements;
  cin >> num_elements;
  int * arr1 = new int[num_elements];
  int x;
  cout << "Enter list:";
  for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
    cin >> x;
    arr1[i] = x;
  }
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;
  count(arr1, num_elements, y, z);
  int * negs = new int [y];
  int * nonNegs = new int[z];
  split(arr1, negs, nonNegs, num_elements, y, z);
  cout << "Negative elements:" << endl;
  print_array(negs, y);
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Non-Negative elements:" << endl;
  print_array(nonNegs, z);
  cout << endl;
```

All functions:

```
void count(int A[], int size, int & negatives, int & nonNegatives) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (A[i] < 0) {
     ++negatives;
    } 
    if (A[i] >= 0) {
     ++nonNegatives;
    }
  }
}

void split(int alpha[], int bravo[], int charlie[], int aSize, int bSize, int cSize) {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < aSize; ++i) {
  if (alpha[i] < 0) {
    alpha[i] = bravo[a];
    ++a;
  }
  else {
    alpha[i] = charlie[b];
    ++b;
  }   
}
 if (a + b != aSize) {
   cout << "SOMETHING HAS GONE HORRIBLY WRONG!";
   exit(0);
 }
}


void print_array(int A[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      cout << A[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

EDIT: I apologize for my unclear question, I was wondering how to get my arrays to behave as I want them to.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Save yourself a lot of headaches and always use `std::array`s and/or `std::vector`s rather than C-style arrays.

Comment: Should not it be `bravo[a] = alpha[i]` and not the inverse ?

Comment: You are copying `bravo` and `charlie` to `alpha` instead of the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Array is behaving correctly as per instruction :), you are doing minor mistake (may be overlook) in split function. I have commented out the statement and given reason of problem, please correct those two line of code, rest is fine.

```
void split(int alpha[], int bravo[], int charlie[], int aSize, int bSize, int cSize) {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < aSize; ++i) {
  if (alpha[i] < 0) {
    //alpha[i] = bravo[a];// here alpha is your source array, don't overwrite it
    bravo[a] = alpha[i];
    ++a;
  }
  else {
    //alpha[i] = charlie[b];// here alpha is your source array, don't overwrite it
    charlie[b] = alpha[i];
    ++b;
  }   
}
 if (a + b != aSize) {
   cout << "SOMETHING HAS GONE HORRIBLY WRONG!";
   exit(0);
 }
}
```